# React function running before state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function that is run when a user clicks a button, when this function is run it gathers data and updates state. I then have another function which runs that uses some of the data that is added to state, the issue is the state is not updating in time so the function is using old data.

### First function

```js
async function callWeather() {
    const key = "";
    // Get location by user
    let location = formData.location;
    // Url for current weather
    const currentWeatherUrl = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${location}&units=metric&appid=${key}`;
    // Get the current weather
    const currentWeatherResponse = await fetch(currentWeatherUrl);
    if (!currentWeatherResponse.ok) {
      // Return this message if an error
      const message = `An error has occured: ${currentWeatherResponse.status}`;
      throw new Error(message);
    }
    const weatherDataResponse = await currentWeatherResponse.json();
    // Update state with data
    setWeatherData(weatherDataResponse);
  }
```

### Second function

```js
async function callForcast() {
    const key = "";
    // Get lat & lon from the previous data fetch
    const lon = weatherData.coord.lon
    const lat = weatherData.coord.lat
    // Get forcast data
    const forcastWeatherUrl = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&units=metric&appid=${key}`
    const forcastWeatherResponse = await fetch(forcastWeatherUrl);
    if (!forcastWeatherResponse.ok) {
      const message = `An error has occured: ${forcastWeatherResponse.status}`;
      throw new Error(message);
    } 
    const forcastDataResponse = await forcastWeatherResponse.json();
    // Update state with the forcast data
    setForcastData(forcastDataResponse);
  }
```

This then runs with the onClick calling both functions

```js
  function callWeatherAndForcast() {
    callForcast();
    callWeather();
  }
```

Comment: Please provide the "setForcastData" and "setWeatherData" methods logic

Comment: React state updates are not immediate. You could look into `useEffect` hook, with the second hook having a dependency on the result of the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

State does not update immediately! Meaning that the function I want to get the new state will get the previous state. To fix this I added callForcast function into a useEffect hook which has a dependency on callWeather because callForcast needs callWeather to update state first. This means when this function is run state will be updated in time.

```js
      useEffect (() => {
        async function callForcast() {
          const key = "";
          // Get lat & lon from the previous data fetch
          const lon = weatherData.coord.lon
          const lat = weatherData.coord.lat
          // Get forcast data
          const forcastWeatherUrl = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&units=metric&appid=${key}`
          const forcastWeatherResponse = await fetch(forcastWeatherUrl);
          if (!forcastWeatherResponse.ok) {
            const message = `An error has occured: ${forcastWeatherResponse.status}`;
            throw new Error(message);
          } 
          const forcastDataResponse = await forcastWeatherResponse.json();
          // Update state with the forcast data
          setForcastData(forcastDataResponse);
        }
        // Call the callForcast function to run
        callForcast();
      },
    // This effect hook is dependent on callWeather
     [callWeather])
```

Now my onClick will only need to call callWeather()
function.

Thanks to:
@Mohammad Arasteh
@Thomas Geenen
@tromgy

Answer (score 3):

use 'await' before calling callForcast so the second function (callWeather) does'nt get called immediately after calling first function.

```
  async function callWeatherAndForcast() {
    await callForcast();
    callWeather();
  }
```

also as @tromgy mentioned in the comments, React state updates are not immediate, try calling callWeather function inside a hook which has a dependency on forcastData state

Answer (score 3):

Are you using FunctionComponent or Classes ?

Also, keep in mind that updating the state will trigger a rerendering. This means that:

1. The state update is not immediate
2. If one of your functions use the data from another, you should take care of these dependencies.

For helping you correctly, I need to know if you use `FunctionComponent` or `Class` and get the whole Function/Class.

**Edit**: *based on the fact that you're using FunctionComponent.*

In order to archive what you want, you need to use `hooks`.

Hooks are the way to handle a function component lifecycle.

For your problem, you'll need `useState`, `useCallback` hooks.

```js
export const DisplayWeather = () => {

    const [forecast, setForecast] = useState();
    const [weather, setWeather] = useState();
    const [error, setError] = useState();

    const onSubmit = useCallback(async () => {
        getWeather();
        getForecast();
    }, [forecast, weather]);

    const getWeather = useCallback(async () => {
        const key = "";
        const location = formData.location;

        const currentWeatherURL = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${location}&units=metric&appid=${key}`;
        const apiResponse = await fetch(currentWeatherURL);

        if(!apiResponse.ok){
            const message = `An error has occured: ${apiResponse.status}`;
            setError(message);
        } else {
            const weatherData = apiResponse.json();
            setWeather(weatherData);
        }
    }, [formData]);

    const getForecast = useCallback(async () => {
        const key = "";

        const lon = weather.coord.lon;
        const lat = weather.coord.lat;

        const forecastWeatherUrl = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&units=metric&appid=${key}`
        const apiResponse = await fetch(forecastWeatherUrl);

        if(!apiResponse.ok) {
            const message = `An error has occured: ${apiResponse.status}`;
            setError(message);
        } else {
            const forecastData = apiResponse.json();
            setForecast(forecastData);
        }
    }, [weather]);

    if(error){
        return (
            <p>Error: {error}</p>
        )
    }
    
    return (
        <p>Forecast data</p>
        <p>{forecast.data.temperature}</p>
        <p>Weather data</p>
        <p>{weather.data.temperature}</p>
    );
}
```

In the code above, I set 2 state variables (weather & forecast) and create 3 functions.

The `onSubmit` function is called when the user click. His callback depend on two variables (weather & forecast) which are referenced in the dependency array (the `[]` after the callback)

The `getWeather` function is called before `getForecast` because the result of the `getForecast` function depends on the weather state. That's why you have `weather` in the `getForecast` callback dependency array. It tells `getForecast` that when the value of `weather` change, it needs to re-render.

Note that i've added `formData` into the dependency array of `getWeather` otherwise, when the user click, the `getWeather` function won't get any value from `formData`.

Note: it is not a working example, just a simple explanation. You can find more infos here:
[Hooks Reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html)
[useCallback Reference](https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/useCallback)

Comment: Hi I am use Function Components.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try to call `callWeather();` under `callForcast()` after `setForcastData()` state set, and if update state value not affected in call weather you can try to add wait in `setForcastData()`.

Or, try to add wait before `callForcast()` in `callWeatherAndForcast()` `onClick`